# How to group dates into month and add a new column after grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

It's my day 7 with SQL. I've a list of dates, I want to group them according to the month. Here's the table. It has only one column i.e. *dateOfService*. The format is *YYYY-MM-DD*.

```
+---------------+
| dateOfService |
+---------------+
| 2020-05-28    |
| 2020-05-29    |
| 2020-05-30    |
| 2020-06-03    |
| 2020-06-05    |
| 2020-07-21    |
| 2020-07-23    |
| 2020-07-25    |
| 2020-07-28    |
+---------------+
```

Ignore the *DD* part, i want to group these dates as follows. Something like:

```
+---------------+---------------+
| monthOfService| dateOfService |
+---------------+---------------+
|    2020-05    |  2020-05-28   |
|               |  2020-05-29   |
|               |  2020-05-30   |
|---------------|---------------|
|    2020-06    |  2020-06-03   |
|               |  2020-06-05   |
|---------------|---------------|
|    2020-07    |  2020-07-21   |
|               |  2020-07-23   |
|               |  2020-07-25   |
|               |  2020-07-28   |
+---------------+---------------+
```

I've to create *monthOfService* from *dateOfService* itself. It's ok if the rows in *monthOfService* repeats. Please tell me approach.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select case when rn = 1 then date_format(dateOfService, '%Y-%m') end monthOfService,
       dateOfService
from (       
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by date_format(dateOfService, '%Y-%m') order by dateOfService) rn
  from tablename
) t
order by dateOfService
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df25f2c20af5681189052539c9fb5a8d).
Results:

```
> monthOfService | dateOfService
> :------------- | :------------
> 2020-05        | 2020-05-28   
> null           | 2020-05-29   
> null           | 2020-05-30   
> 2020-06        | 2020-06-03   
> null           | 2020-06-05   
> 2020-07        | 2020-07-21   
> null           | 2020-07-23   
> null           | 2020-07-25   
> null           | 2020-07-28
```

If you want the values of `monthOfService` repeated then:

```
select date_format(dateOfService, '%Y-%m') monthOfService,
       dateOfService
from tablename
order by dateOfService
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32eb0a7104677b8616d693632a63ef59).
Results:

```
> monthOfService | dateOfService
> :------------- | :------------
> 2020-05        | 2020-05-28   
> 2020-05        | 2020-05-29   
> 2020-05        | 2020-05-30   
> 2020-06        | 2020-06-03   
> 2020-06        | 2020-06-05   
> 2020-07        | 2020-07-21   
> 2020-07        | 2020-07-23   
> 2020-07        | 2020-07-25   
> 2020-07        | 2020-07-28
```

Comment: Instead of `null`. Can we just repeat the above _YYYY-MM_ ? That will be good.

Comment: See my 2nd query.

Comment: Awesome. The second query is what I'm looking for. :-)
Please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: The 2nd query is very simple: the function `date_format(dateOfService, '%Y-%m')` returns only the year-month part of each date.

Comment: Check here some examples: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986019/how-to-calculate-running-sum-for-each-group-in-mysql

Comment: Hi, can you please look into this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004031/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-partitioning-in-sql

I'm facing some version issues i think.

Comment: @Tanzeel I saw your question. You can't do it in versions of MySql prior to 8.0. You have to upgrade.

Comment: So, is the syntax different or partitioning doesn't works at all in 8.0 ?

Comment: It does not work at all in 5.7. It was introduced in version 8.0

Comment: Ok. So what is the best alternative?

Comment: @Tanzeel all your other questions were about version 8.0 Why do you use a prior version now? There is no *best* alternative. The only way that you could do something like that involves using variables that are now deprecated and will not work in the future or joins and aggregation that are very complicated.

Comment: I was running queries on my local (v.8.0) but today i came to know that my company is using v.5.7. I told them to upgrade. But my boss says no because then other things will start falling apart. Now i've to refactor all the queries. :-(

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5e56c1456b1c0ceed1cef0546745cf63

Comment: This is what I meant, in this fiddle you use variables to calculate the running sum.

Comment: Now again I'm facing the same problem. That Reward1 and Reward2 'Y' - 'N' values if you rememeber, where sum>=10 and sum>20 respectively. Can you edit the above given fiddle accordingly. I'm blocked. Seriously need your help.

Comment: @Tanzeel I would not even have posted an answer for this requirement, if I knew that I couldn't use window functions like row_number().

Comment: Even I didn't know. Just now She (my boss) told me to query things for V5.7. Please help. I'm also trying in parallel.

Comment: I have not written code for such requirements without the use of window functions for years now, because such code is deprecated and (tell your boss) it may not work when you will (eventually) upgrade to the latest version of MySql. What you can do is ask a new question where you mention that you want a solution without window functions. For this, I can't help you.

Comment: Oh. That's a bad new for me. :-(

Comment: But thanks for your time. :-) Can you please ask this to your friends: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005360/how-to-achieve-partition-by-kind-of-functionality-using-variables-in-mysql-5-7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_concat()`:

```
select extract(year_month from date) as yyyymm, group_concat(date)
from t
group by yyyymm;
```

This uses the default commas separator for the list.  That is more common than using a new line in a SQL query.

Comment: Excellent, but i'm getting commas. `2020-05 | 2020-05-28,2020-05-29,2020-05-30`.
Table name is `mytable`

Comment: I want them in sepaarte rows. even if monthOfservice repeats

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025684/how-to-use-group-by-in-a-query-while-using-variables