# What is the correct syntax for partitioning in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table *PatientAppointment*. There is only 2 columns *AppointmentDateTime* and *Duration* which stores date and total hr or minutes for which that particular patient had his appointment. Let us assume there is only one patient for now. I'm facing issues with partitioning. Here is the table:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
| AppointmentDateTime | Duration        |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2020-05-28          |   30 min        |
| 2020-05-29          |   30 min        |
| 2020-05-30          |   1 hour        |
| 2020-06-03          |   1 hour        |
| 2020-06-05          |   1 hour 30 min |
| 2020-07-21          |   1 hour 30 min |
| 2020-07-22          |   1 hour        |
| 2020-07-28          |   30 min        |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Here is the query. I'm first converting duration to minutes in integer like 30, 60, 90 so that I can sum them up. Then I've to partition them month wise. It should look like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e278ae46a79b4a8fe376b050368c370). This works on fiddle.

```
select 
sum(((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) +
(case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end))) over (partition by date_format(pa.AppointmentDateTime, '%Y-%m') order by pa.AppointmentDateTime) total
from PatientAppointment pa
```

This works on fiddle. But gives error on my local:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by date_format(pa.AppointmentDateTime, '%Y-%m') order by pa.Appointme' at line 3

My local version are:

innodb_version 5.7.26, protocol_version 10, tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
version 5.7.26-log

Please help me what to do now.

Comment: Versions of MySQL prior to 8 do not support this syntax. Upgrade or rewrite your query.

Comment: oh no. What should i do now. Please help me. I tried using window functions but failed again.

Comment: For your version - calculate cumulative sum using user-defined variables.

Comment: Likewise. Upgrade or rewrite. The better strategy is to upgrade. But for help with rewriting, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Akina, I need cumulative sum for each month not for the entire column.

Comment: *I need cumulative sum for each month not for the entire column.* This only needs one more variable which stores year-month value.

Comment: @Akina, Here is a demo. Plz see this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3e278ae46a79b4a8fe376b050368c370

Comment: Cumulative sum using UDV - see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5e56c1456b1c0ceed1cef0546745cf63). PS. Output columns order is critical - but it doesn't matter if this example is used as a subquery or the output data is accessed by column names.

Comment: @Akina, this will do. Please add this as the answer i'll accept his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cumulative sum using UDV:

```sql
select
dateOfCheckup,
duration,

-- use intermediate variable @cur_dur for not calculate this value twice
@cur_dur := ((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) +
(case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)) as minutes,

-- check does current @year_month is equal to previous, continue or restart @cum_sum
CASE WHEN @year_month = date_format(dateOfCheckup, '%Y-%m')
     THEN @cum_sum := @cum_sum + @cur_dur
     ELSE @cum_sum := @cur_dur
     END total,

-- store current @year_month for to use with next row
@year_month := date_format(dateOfCheckup, '%Y-%m') monthOfCheckup

from patient, 

-- initialize variables which will be used
(SELECT @year_month:='', @cum_sum:=0, @cur_dur:=0) variables

-- the rows must be processed in definite order
ORDER BY dateOfCheckup
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5e56c1456b1c0ceed1cef0546745cf63)

Output columns order is critical (the calulations in output columns in a row are performed strictly in the order in which they're written). But it doesn't matter if this example is used as a subquery or the output data is accessed by column names.

Comment: @Tanzeel . . . This use of variables is highly dangerous, because the same variable is assigned in one statement and then used in another.  The documentation *explicitly* warns against this:  "As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)  You use this at your peril.