# How to achieve partition by kind of functionality using variables in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I'm using an old version of MySQL. I cannot upgrade it due to some strong reasons. I've a table *PatientAppointment* with only 2 columns. Here is the table:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
| dateOfCheckup       | duration        |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2020-05-28          |   30 min        |
| 2020-05-29          |   30 min        |
| 2020-05-30          |   1 hour        |
| 2020-06-03          |   1 hour        |
| 2020-06-05          |   1 hour 30 min |
| 2020-07-21          |   1 hour 30 min |
| 2020-07-22          |   1 hour        |
| 2020-07-28          |   30 min        |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

I want 5 things:

1. Create a new column in runtime *monthOfCheckup* from *dateOfCheckup*
2. Convert *duration* into integer field as *minutes*
3. Accumulating *total* for each month (not date)

I was able to achieve these 3 points with this query:

```
select
dateOfCheckup,
duration,
@cur_dur := ((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) +
(case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)) as minutes,

CASE WHEN @year_month = date_format(dateOfCheckup, '%Y-%m')
     THEN @cum_sum := @cum_sum + @cur_dur
     ELSE @cum_sum := @cur_dur
     END total,
@year_month := date_format(dateOfCheckup, '%Y-%m') monthOfCheckup

from patient, (SELECT @year_month:='', @cum_sum:=0, @cur_dur:=0) variables
ORDER BY dateOfCheckup
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=18b79e58b3bbd83342d6fd46667e34da) for the same.

Now the remaining 2 points are:

4. *BillElig1* This can be boolean or text, doesn't matters. I just have to put 'Y' if the *total* for that particular month is >=20
5. *BillElig2* This can be boolean or text, doesn't matters. I just have to put 'Y' if the *total* for that particular month is >=40

For these 2 points you can see this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e278ae46a79b4a8fe376b050368c370).

Please help me.

Comment: *For these 2 points you can see* I see that these points are not "when is" (easy) but "when reach" (hard in your version).

Comment: anyway, let's try that. I'm working on this since 15 hours. Plz help me :-(

Comment: I dont care whether you put remaining values to 'N' or just leave them blank.

Comment: Using "when is" will put all the values to 'Y' for that month because of accumulating _total_

Comment: Please add your desired result.

Comment: @P.Salmon, here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e278ae46a79b4a8fe376b050368c370

Should look like this but for version 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And again use UDV.

```sql
SELECT dateOfCheckup,
       duration,
       minutes,
       CASE WHEN @prev_month != monthOfCheckup
            THEN total >= 20
            WHEN @prev_total < 20 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
            END 99457Elig,
       CASE WHEN @prev_month != monthOfCheckup
            THEN total >= 40
            WHEN @prev_total < 40
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
            END 99458Elig,
       @prev_month := monthOfCheckup monthOfCheckup,
       @prev_total := total total
FROM (select dateOfCheckup,
             duration,
             @cur_dur := ((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) +
                         (case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)) as minutes,

             CASE WHEN @year_month = date_format(dateOfCheckup, '%Y-%m')
                  THEN @cum_sum := @cum_sum + @cur_dur
                  ELSE @cum_sum := @cur_dur
                  END total,
             @year_month := date_format(dateOfCheckup, '%Y-%m') monthOfCheckup

      from patient, (SELECT @year_month:='', @cum_sum:=0, @cur_dur:=0) variables
      ORDER BY dateOfCheckup) subquery, 
(SELECT @prev_month:=0, @prev_total:=0) variable
ORDER BY dateOfCheckup
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=754883a77d611dab611631f55cf660e6)

I use `1` and `0` instead of `Y` and `NULL`.

Of course, the columns order in output list and ordering are critical again.